# Issue with Python Flask

Tags: python, url-routing

I'm currently working on a Flask application, and I'm facing a problem with routing. I have defined routes in my "app.py" file, but for some reason, the application is not routing requests as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, this is the home page!'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'This is the about page.'

# Additional routes...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to access these routes, I get unexpected results. For instance, going to /about gives me a 404 error. I've checked the code and the Flask documentation, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Any insights into why my routes might not be working as expected would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just tested and this code works fine for me.

Comment: i just went to  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/about` and it is fine.

Comment: do you run it on local computer? Do you try to connect from local computer? What do you see when you run it in console/terminal? It should show what address you have to use in browser, and it should show error when it can't generate response.